# Question about Automate The Boring Stuff Chapter 3

Tags: python

I am on chapter three of Automate The Boring Stuff with Python. For exercise guessTheNumber.py I am unclear as to how "guessesTaken" was defined and how it is being incremented.

https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter3/

How is this program:
1. Defining the guessesTaken variable
2. increasing the value of guessesTaken for each guess

Thank you,

```
# This is a guess the number game.
import random
secretNumber = random.randint(1, 20)
print('I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')

# Ask the player to guess 6 times.
for guessesTaken in range(1, 7):
    print('Take a guess.')
    guess = int(input())

    if guess < secretNumber:
        print('Your guess is too low.')
    elif guess > secretNumber:
        print('Your guess is too high.')
    else:
        break # this condition is the correct guess!

if guess == secretNumber:
    print('Good job! You guessed my number in ' + str(guessesTaken) +' guesses!')
else:
    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + str(secretNumber))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is used as a loop counter, it was defined in:

```
for guessesTaken in range(1, 7):
```

And is being incremented in every iteration of the for loop. So if the loop counter reaches `3`, that means the loop ran (didn't `break`) three times, and so the user had to guess three times.

Comment: Thanks. So is guessesTaken being created and assigned to a new number each time the loop runs?